# How to dynamically add a src on my script tag on angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have a `js` file `configuration.js` :

```
window.__env = {};
window.__env.config = {
 dynamic_script:'https://path-to-my-js-script.js/',
}
```

I want to include this `dynamic_script` into my angular `index.html` :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="HOW_TO_GET_THE_VALUE_HERE"></script>
```

So in src, I want to have `https://path-to-my-js-script.js/` that should come from my `configuration.js` file.
Any herlp ?

Comment: As the script needs access to the JS variables, why not create the script tag in JS? `document.createElement('script') ... etc`

Comment: `[src]="variable"` doesn't work?

Comment: @DanielB I think it should work but what you call "variable" should come from js file, so is there a way to make the connection ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sounds also good, but should I add document.createElement in main.ts ?

Comment: If that’s where it makes sense.